# group by year on multiple date columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have table as following:

```
hours  | ... | task_assigned  | task_deadline  | task_completion
----------------------------------------------------------------
123    | ... | 2019-08-01     | -              | -
234    | ... | -              | 2018-08-01     | 2019-08-01
145    | ... | 2017-08-01     | 2017-08-01     | 2018-01-01
```

I want to calculate total hours for each year, i.e. grouping by year.

Currently I'm only taking into account `task_completion` field.

If there's no value in `task_completion` field, the record is not included in `SUM` calculation.

To elaborate further, say for `year 2019`, row `1` and `1` both should be considered. Hence the total hours should be `123 + 234 = 357`.

And for `year 2018`, row `2 and 3`.

Similarly, for `year 2017`, row `3`.

```
SELECT YEAR(task_completion) as year, ROUND(SUM(total_hours), 2) as hours 
FROM task
GROUP BY year
HAVING year BETWEEN '$year_from' AND '$year_to'
```

The resultset:

```
year  |  hours
--------------------
2017  |  <somevalue>
2018  |  <somevalue>
2019  |  <somevalue>
```

How can I include other two date fields too?

Comment: How should your result set look like?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I've updated the post. please check.

Comment: Do you want your resultset to include the other two date columns?

Comment: @helloworld .. yes.. currently if there's no value for `task_completion` field, then that record is not used for sum calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to consider each row once for each of its years. Use `UNION` to get these years:

```
select year, round(sum(total_hours), 2) as hours
from
(
  select year(task_assigned) as year, total_hours from task
  union
  select year(task_deadline) as year, total_hours from task
  union
  select year(task_completion) as year, total_hours from task
) years_and_hours
group by year
having year between $year_from and $year_to
order by year;
```

If you want to consider a row with one year twice or thrice also as often in the sum, then change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to unpivot the data.  I will assume that the `-` represents a `NULL` value and your dates are real dates.

```
select year(dte) as year, sum(total_hours) as hours
from ((select task_assigned as dte, total_hours
       from task
      ) union all
      (select task_deadline, total_hours
       from task
      ) union all
      (select task_completion, total_hours
       from task
      )
     ) d
where dte is not null
group by year(dte)
order by year(dte);
```

Based on your sample data, the `round()` is not necessary so I removed it.

If you want to filter for particular years, the filtering should be in a `where` clause -- so it filters the data *before* aggregation.

Change the `where` to:

```
where year(dte) >= ? and year(dte) <= ?
```

or:

```
where dte >= ? and dte <= ?
```

to pass in the dates.

The `?` are for parameter placeholders.  Learn how to use parameters rather than munging query strings.

Comment: passing date parameters will only concern `task_assigned` field?

Comment: @Azima . . . I don't understand your comment.  There is no such reference in the question.

Comment: @Azima . . . You accepted an answer; why do you continue to ask questions?  If you have another question, then ask as a question.  `dte` is all three columns combined into a single column, so it is sometimes `task_assigned`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is no langer valid with the updated request.

<strike>If I understand correctly, you want to use `task_assigned` if the `task_completion` is still null. Use `COALEASCE` for this.</strike>

```
SELECT
  YEAR(COALESCE(task_completion, task_assigned)) as year,
  ROUND(SUM(total_hours), 2) as hours
FROM task
GROUP BY year
HAVING year BETWEEN $year_from AND $year_to
ORDER BY year;
```

(I don't think you actually want to use `task_deadline`, too, for how could a task get completed before getting assigned first? If such can occur, then include it in the `COALESCE` expression. Probably: COALESCE(task_completion, task_assigned, task_deadline)` then.)

Comment: I've updated the post.. hope it will clear the confusion.

Comment: but say, a row has `task_completion` value as `2019-09-09` and `task_assigned` as `2018-09-21`. And I'm looking SUM(hours) for `2018` and hence this row should also be considered. But with COALESCE(), since `task_completion` is not null, it will take `2019` as `year` and hence ignore the row.